# Tcp Socket not getting connected

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets, tcpsocket

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Try
                Dim reply As String = "v1.0"
                If reply <> S_Settings.StubVer Then
                    S_Messages.Messages("{ New update is available! }", "Get to me")
                ElseIf reply = S_Settings.StubVer Then
                    S_Messages.Messages("{ You are using the latest version! }", "Bugs :Contact me")
                End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try


        Dim Client As Net.Sockets.TcpClient = Nothing
        Dim PortLabel As New Text.StringBuilder
        For Each ThePort In S_Settings.PORT
            Try
                If GetExternalAddress() = "127.0.0.1" Then
                    PortLabel.Append(String.Format(" {0}=OPENED ", ThePort))
                    MetroLabel3.Text = String.Format("IP={0} {1} KEY={2}", GetExternalAddress, PortLabel.ToString, "abcd")
                    MetroLabel3.ForeColor = Color.Lime
                Else
                    Client = New Net.Sockets.TcpClient
                    Client.Connect(GetExternalAddress, ThePort)
                    PortLabel.Append(String.Format(" {0}=OPENED ", ThePort))
                    MetroLabel3.Text = String.Format("IP={0} {1} KEY={2}", GetExternalAddress, PortLabel.ToString, "abcd")
                    MetroLabel3.ForeColor = Color.Lime
                End If
            Catch ex As Net.Sockets.SocketException
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString() + " 1")
                MetroProgressSpinner1.Spinning = False
                PortLabel.Append(String.Format(" {0}=CLOSED ", ThePort))
                MetroLabel3.Text = String.Format("IP={0}  {1}  KEY={2}", GetExternalAddress, PortLabel.ToString, "abcd")
                MetroLabel3.ForeColor = Color.Red
                'Try : My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources._Error, AudioPlayMode.Background) : Catch : End Try 'https://freesound.org/people/eardeer/sounds/385281/

                If GTV("FW") = Nothing Then
                    Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Port " & ThePort & " seems to be blocked" + Environment.NewLine + "Do you want to add myProg into firewall exception", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
                    If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
                        Try
                            STV("FW", "1")
                            Dim process As New Process()
                            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                            process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
                            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
                            process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"
                            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=""myProg"" dir=in action=allow program=""" & Application.ExecutablePath & """ enable=yes"
                            process.Start()
                            process.WaitForExit()
                            Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath)
                            End
                        Catch ex1 As Exception
                            MessageBox.Show(ex1.ToString() + " 2")
                        End Try
                    End If
                End If
            Finally
                Try : Client.Close() : Catch : End Try
            End Try
        Next

    End Sub
```

I am getting the following exception and don't know how to resolve it:
[image: exception images]

Why the port is not connecting? I have put all the firewall to off.
Let me know what I can do.

Comment: Please don't tag questions that are obviously about VB.NET with C#. Although they run on the same Runtime and Framework they are two entirely different languages

Comment: @MindSwipe Understood. Do you have anything else to say on the issue? Let me know.

Comment: ...cuz theres like no server to connect to?

Comment: @HirasawaYui I did not understood? Please can you explain me. I am kinda new to socket programming with vb.

Comment: This probably isn't a coding issue but a connectivity one. Perhaps the server isn't running, perhaps it's a firewall issue, perhaps something else. Does it work with localhost (127.0.0.1)?

Comment: What are you trying to connect to? I can see clients in your code... but where is the server? Is it configured correctly? Is it accepting connections? It looks like you're getting a timeout, so it might be a good idea to make sure your server is accessible and works as expected.

Comment: It is on the server and not on the client side. I am trying to connect the system using the above code. Am I doing it wrongly?